# Массив уникальных массивов. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть некий скрипт сбора координат вида `[2,1]` в массив. Координаты могут повторяться, но итоговый массив должен содержать только уникальные координаты.

Я делаю следующим образом:

```
let arr = [];
for(...){
    //Собираем координаты в строковом виде, чтобы сразу отбросить повторяющиеся
    let str = [i, j].join();
    !arr.includes(str) && arr.push(str)
}

//Приводим координаты к первоначальному формату
arr = arr.map(str => {
    let coords = str.split(',');
    return [parseInt(coords[0]), parseInt(coords[1])];
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли более элегантный способ? Без приведения к строке и тд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a = [1,2];
const b = [3,4];
const c = [5,6];
const d = [3,4];
const arr = [a,b,c,d]
const obj = {}
arr.forEach(item => {
  obj[item] = item
});
const result = Object.values(obj);

console.log(result)
```

С помощью reduce, как советовал @Grundy

```js
const a = [1,2];
const b = [3,4];
const c = [5,6];
const d = [3,4];
const arr = [a,b,c,d]
let result = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  obj[curr] = curr;
}, obj={});
result = Object.values(obj);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Или я не так объяснил, или вы не так поняли. На выходе должны быть координаты в виде массивов [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]

Comment: внес изменения.

Comment: Спасибо, не знал, что можно массив использовать в качестве названия свойства объекта

Comment: @FelAA, нельзя, он точно так же вызовет `toString` у массива и ключ на самом деле будет `1,2` а не массив.

Comment: Сам в шоке)....

Comment: @FelAA, что-то кроме строки и symbol в качестве "ключа" можно использовать только в [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) но там тогда будут проблемы при сравнении.

Comment: @Дмытрык, вместо `forEach` тут лучше `reduce`

Comment: @Grundy Почему лучше reduce?

Comment: @FelAA, потому что в данном случае его функционал реализуется с помощью `forEach` и глобального объекта.

Comment: @Grundy, сделал с помощью reduce. Так имелось ввиду?

Comment: `result = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {}));`